# How do I run my program (and dbus) as a service on a headless server?

Tags: fedora, systemd, d-bus, headless

I have a Fedora 20 server running headless, which I want to run my service.  I'd like it managed by systemd so that it runs whenever the server is powered on.

My service is written in Python, and uses dbus to activate and control some third-party program.  I believe this means there must be an instance of dbus running in session mode?

How do I hook all this into systemd?  Start a dbus daemon in a session, run my program in the same session, and stop/restart them in a sane way?